# How do I set Layout and Text size to DP inside program?

Tags: java, android, layout

Basically I have this inside XML, but I have to recreate it inside a code. How do I do it?

```
<EditText 
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_bg01"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="111-222-333     FOOO" />
```

I can use this to set text size, but what about the layout_width and height?

```
edTxt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10);
```

Is there a way to tell the code to use DP unit instead of pixel? Or a conversion function to convert DP into pixel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is textview.setTextSize()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590943/what-is-textview-settextsize)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android specifying pixel units (like sp, px, dp) without using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012840/android-specifying-pixel-units-like-sp-px-dp-without-using-xml)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012840/android-specifying-pixel-units-like-sp-px-dp-without-using-xml/5012893#5012893).

Extract:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float dp = 20f;
float fpixels = metrics.density * dp;
int pixels = (int) (fpixels + 0.5f);
```

Comment: note, it would be `.scaledDensity` BUT this solution DOES NOT now seem to work on modern androids (it comes out way too big)

Comment: .. when setting the text size

Answer (score 95):

You can use:

```
float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Now the value of `pixels` is equivalent to `10dp` at the device's current screen density.

The [TypedValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html) contains other similar methods that help in conversion.

Answer (score 22):

Just for completeness: Another solution (which I'd prefer) for the question is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19497680/5119746)

> `setTextSize(float)` expects a scaled pixel value. So, `setTextSize(10)` would give you the desired result. However, `getDimension()` and `getDimensionPixelSize()` return the size in units of pixels.

So for your example it would be

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.edTxt_text_size));
```

where `<dimen name="edtxt_text_size">10dp</dimen>` is set in your dimens.xml file for example.

Answer (score 2):

### Regarding setting the TEXT SIZE:

For 2021 ...

Fortunately, the correct modern answer is just

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25);
```

or you can use COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, etc.

### Exactly matches xml for text size:

Checked, on all devices this produces exactly the same result as just setting it in xml:

[image]

---

### Regarding setting, say, a layout parameter:

```
int h = 66; // the new value
ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = some_frame.getLayoutParams();
float fdp = TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
    h,
    getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
p.height = Math.round(fdp);
some_frame.setLayoutParams(p);
```

This appears to work correctly, on a test device. The value "h" is now the "same" as simply in the xml, enter 66dp.

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin to increase/decrease font size with below logic. It works in 2

```
 `  private var fontSize: Float = 17F //default font size
    
    btnTextDecrease.setOnClickListener {
       if (fontSize <= 13F) {return@setOnClickListener}
       fontSize -= 0.5F
       etBook.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize)
       Toast.makeText(activity, "Decrease Size$fontSize", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    btnTextIncrease.setOnClickListener {
       fontSize += 0.5F
       etBook.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize)
       Toast.makeText(activity, "Increase Size$fontSize", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }`
```