# Android specifying pixel units (like sp, px, dp) without using XML

Tags: android, android-layout, pixel

Is it possible to specify the pixel unit in code. 
What I mean is, say I have a layout and I want the size to be 20dp, then is there any way to do so without writing in a layout xml

Comment: correct modern answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66459077/294884

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In a view:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float dp = 20f;
float fpixels = metrics.density * dp;
int pixels = (int) (fpixels + 0.5f);
```

In an Activity, of course, you leave off the `getContext()`.

To convert from scaled pixels (`sp`) to pixels, just use `metrics.scaledDensity` instead of `metrics.density`.

EDIT: As [@Santosh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11608530/535871) points out, you can do the same thing using the utility class [`TypedValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float dp = 20f;
float fpixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, metrics);
int pixels = Math.round(fpixels);
```

For `sp`, substitute `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP` for `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP`.

Internally, `applyDimension()` does exactly the same calculation as my code above. Which version to use is a matter of your coding style.

Comment: To round up, this is what the framework does. This ensures that the size will never be 0px.

Comment: @sebrock - Because OP wanted the size to be 20dp and making it a float to start with eliminates an int-to-float conversion when calculating `pixels` two lines later.

Comment: sry to bring up an old topic but i have a question.  What if i have a value stored in a variable that i want the dp equal to. For example if i have a random value stored in the variable num how do i replace the 20f with numf.

Comment: @MikeT - I don't quite understand the problem. If you want to use the sample code I posted, just use the variable instead of `dp` (or assign `dp` the value of your variable: `float dp = randomVariable;`).

Comment: @wviana - You would use `metrics.scaledDensity` instead of `metrics.density` in the last line. I'll update the answer to include that information. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @Fattie - That's a good solution for setting text size. But it doesn't generalize to other cases (say, setting a layout dimension in code). Also, that API call has been around since Android 1, so it isn't new for 2021.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

now, the value of `pixels` is equivalent to `20dp`

The [TypedValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html) contains other similar methods that help in conversion