# Android SlidingMenu with Jfeinstein10 library

Tags: android

how to set the width of SlidingMenu.I mean the sliding menu occupies the entire screen when i use getSlidingMenu().showMenu()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you got to use this line of code

```
menu.setBehindOffset(int offsetInPixels);
```

and if you want to support proportion you got to use system resources.

```
this.getResources().getInt(R.integer.offsetInPixels);
```

where offsetInPixels is `<integer name="offsetInPixels">your offset</integer>`
in res/values... res/values-large.... res/values-xlarge...

I'm not able to post an image, and if you'll mark this post as an answer - i'll be able and show you properly with images.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java code:

```
 /*
  * Sets the behind width.
  *
  * @param i The width the Sliding Menu will open to, in pixels
  */    
  setBehindWidth(int i)
```

See [Reference](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/SlidingMenu.java) from source code of jfeistein10's github

Or if you are using XML to define the sliding menu:

```
sliding:behindWidth="@dimen/YOUR_WIDTH"
```

See [Reference](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu#xml-usage)

Comment: Can we specify it in proportion to the screen width.Because right now when i try to give the width 690 it looks good on bluestack but when iuse it on my device it is going out of the screen

Comment: @YashPatil yes, you can. Please look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11608619/763459