# Set text size in .xml or programmatically

Tags: android, dimensions

I have variable at dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="btn_text_size">12sp</dimen>    
</resources>
```

And i can use it in layout file:

```
 <TextView
           android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text_size"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dialog_tags_complete"
/>
```

or programmatically

```
tagButton.setTextSize(c.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.tag_text_size));
```

But this 2 methods give different results. I know that `getDimension` are based on the current DisplayMetrics associated with the resources.

But what should i do to make this 2 ways looks the same?

Comment: Use `getDimensionPixelSize()`.

Comment: @323go i tested it on my HTC One S. Yhere is no difference between  getDimensionPixelSize() and getDimension() =/

Comment: And you do realize that `sp` = scaled pixels, which will adjust based on the screen metrics and text-scaling factor, right? If you want to make them look the same, you'll need to use `dp`.

Comment: @323go why the same dimension look different if it set programmatically (vs .xml setting)?

Comment: Because you're using the wrong `setTextSize()` method. The one you're using expects scaled pixels, while you are providing pixels. Do this instead: `setTextSize( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen.tag_text_size ) );`

Comment: @323go oh, right. I'm stupid =D
Tnx, it helps.

Comment: Nothing about "being stupid" here -- it's easy to miss.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`setTextSize( float )` expects a scaled pixel value. So, `setTextSize( 12 )` would give you the desired result. However, `getDimension()` and `getDimensionPixelSize()` return the size in units of pixels, so you need to use the unit-typed variant of `setTextSize()` as follows:

```
setTextSize( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen.tag_text_size ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tagButton.setTextSize(c.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.tag_text_size));
```

this will work just fine :)
You should also remember that textView has a setTextSize(int unit,float size), which should be used while setting size from code but not from xml dimen.

Comment: It's still looking different from setting in .xml. Or should i set ALL size of ALL views programmatically to make no difference?

Answer (score 0):

I have currently the same thing. Did set a dimension in dimens.xml and applied it programmatically, which is 3 times that big, than when settings via xml.

I checked also:

```
TextView.getTextSize() = 92f
getResources().getDimension(R.dimen ...) = 92f
```

TextView.setTextSize(92) != TextView with size from XML, other flags like TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX make it even bigger.

The default setTextSize does apply COMPLEX_UNIT_SP by default btw. So once again, the Android API is inconsistent, so setting programmatically only and adapt sizes, so they fit, will be my solution.

Edit: Setting text size programmatically under Galaxy Note 2 (4.4.2) vs Note 4 (5.0.1) leads to a totally different result -.-