# What is textview.setTextSize()?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

In my android game, there is a textview. I am setting the text size using following code.

```
textview.setTextSize(30);
```

`30` is in pixels. But what exactly it is ? Is it the height or width of a character ? Is it ordinal no. ?

Comment: It will just increase text size.it s not about height n width.both will increase.ya you can increase size of TextView.

Comment: Also downvoting this because you can look up Android documentation yourself.

Comment: @aamit915 this issue is not addressed in documentation.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I see now what your question is. How does Android measure the size of text. My mistake. Unfortunately it is too late for me to change the vote. I'm pretty sure it's based on the height of a bounding box that can encompass the highest and lowest letters, but I can't find any confirmation of that.

Comment: [A solution that works well for both orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77290596/1066828)

Answer (score 3):

for set text size in android (java or kotlin) just use SP

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
```

Comment: `setTextSize()` already uses `sp` units by default. `getTextSize()` returns pixels, though.

Answer (score 1):

@Rasoul Miri's answer works well for Java because Java does type promotion for numbers.

Kotlin, on the other hand won't lift a finger and would just pedantically nag you with:

`The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Float`

So, be sure to beg it to do explicit conversion for you with a : `.toFloat()` call.

So, @Rasoul's example becomes.

`textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14.toFloat());`

NB: Would have added this as edit to @Rasoul's answer but StackOverflow says `The suggested Edit queue is full`.