# Make square image in Glide and then round it

Tags: android, android-glide

I solve a typical task for image: try to `centerCrop()` it and make circular like in [How to round an image with Glide library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278821/how-to-round-an-image-with-glide-library), but a result seems like [Glide circular image gets cropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594330/glide-circular-image-gets-cropped) or [image]

(not circular).

I think Glide (v.4) doesn't correctly crop the image. I tried many variants like `GlideApp.with(photo).load(url).circleCrop().into(photo)`. Probably better would be first to create a square from a rectangle and then make it circular.

This is a part of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/image_1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="1sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/photo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/photo"
        tools:text="Name"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

UPDATE

Sorry, a problem was in a source image. I didn't think it was squared with white paddings above and below (lines are added):

[image]

And another example:

[image]

This is because on a backend they *downscaled rectangular image making it square with white borders*.

Comment: Better to use [`CircleImageView`](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView). It's easy and effective.

Comment: @RumitPatel, yes, but if I have Glide, probably it can handle cropping.

Comment: yes @CoolMind , you wrote you have tried and *Glide (v.4) doesn't correctly crop the image.* so I suggested alternate and better way. I had same issue and I preferred to use [`CircleImageView.`](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) :-)

Comment: @RumitPatel, thanks. Strange that you have a namesake here. :)

Comment: @RumitPatel, sorry, I updated the question.

Comment: Any way to tell Glide to crop a specific rectangle of the bitmap?

Comment: @androiddeveloper, maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679329/android-glide-crop-cut-off-x-pixels-from-image-bottom?

Comment: @CoolMind So it's not part of Glide? Weird.

Comment: @androiddeveloper, you are right, it's strange.

Answer (score 6):

Use `RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()`

Like this :

```
    Glide.with(this).load(url)
            .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
            .into((ImageView) photo);
```

Plus, make sure the ImageView is a square. If you are using ConstraintLayout, use `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"`

Doc : https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestOptions.html

Comment: Yes, I have a square `ImageView` (50x50). Sorry, but a result is the same.

Comment: @CoolMind then post the xml layout please

Comment: Ok, I added it.

Comment: Thanks for this tip `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way xml after taking the picture

```
   <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   />

    dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please check below answer :**

**Try it and let me know if any question regarding it.**

```
private RequestOptions circleOptions = new RequestOptions()
            .centerCrop()
            .circleCrop()      // responsible for circle crop
            .placeholder(R.color.color_gray)    // replace with your placeholder image or remove if don't want to set
            .error(R.color.color_gray)     // replace with your placeholder image or remove if don't want to set
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE);

public void loadImageCircle(String url, ImageView view) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .apply(circleOptions)
                .into(view);
    }
```

> Call method as :

```
loadImageCircle(imafgeURL,imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

A problem was in the image. I tried to make a circle from a square that contained white paddings on both sides.

[image]

Then I used an original rectangular image without paddings.

[image]

```
GlideApp.with(imageView)
    .load(url)
    .transform(CircleCrop())
    .into(imageView)
```

Looking at [Glide Multiple transformations in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759841/glide-multiple-transformations-in-android/63798242), I found that we can first create a square by cropping the rectangle and then make rounded corners.

```
val transformation = MultiTransformation(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(10))
GlideApp.with(imageView)
    .load(url)
    .transform(transformation)
    .into(imageView)
```

[image]